# Insert entire row based upon prompted cell value

Tags: vba, excel

All, I have the following code, but I need to know how to amend it. I need a prompt or message box that asks me, which value in column A to look for. It should the find the corresponding value in Sheet1 Column A, and copy the Data from Column A to AL over to sheet2.

Here's my code:

```
Sub MM1()
  Dim Check As Range, r As Long, lastrow2 As Long, lastrow As Long
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
  lastrow2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
  If lastrow2 = 1 Then lastrow2 = 0
    For r = lastrow To 2 Step -1
      If Range("E" & r).Value = "Yes" Then
        Rows(r).Cut Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & lastrow2 + 1)
        lastrow2 = lastrow2 + 1
    Else:
  End If
  Next r
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Also, this is to be a subset of code which will search for the exact row to insert at.

Comment: For starters you can prompt inputbox by `myInput = InputBox("Enter search string")` and then use your `myInput` variable to search within Column A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do a manual loop through the rows in sheet1, just use VBA's native [`Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) function. Also You're currently not getting user input, that can be achieved with an [`InputBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839468.aspx).

See the comments for details about the code.

---

**This example copies the data from the first match**:

```
Sub MM1()
    Dim lastrowsheet2 As Long
    ' Use last cell in UsedRange for its row number, 
    ' if row 1,2,... aren't used, then UsedRange will be shorter than you expect!
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange
        lastrowsheet2 = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
    End With
    ' Get user input for a search term
    Dim userinput As String
    userinput = InputBox("Enter a value to search for.", "Column A Search")
    ' Search for value
    Dim findrange As Range
    Set findrange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Find(what:=userinput, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If findrange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No matching search results"
    Else
        lastrowsheet2 = lastrowsheet2 + 1
        ' Copy values in found row to sheet 2, in new last row
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & lastrowsheet2, "AL" & lastrowsheet2).Value _
            = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & findrange.Row, "AL" & findrange.Row).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

---

**This example copies the data from the every match in the column**:

```
Sub MM1()
    ' Speed improvements
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    ' Use last cell in UsedRange for its row number,
    ' if row 1,2,... aren't used, then UsedRange will be shorter than you expect!
    Dim lastrowsheet2 As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange
        lastrowsheet2 = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
        ' If sheet is completely empty, make sure data will be inserted on row 1 not 2
        If lastrowsheet2 = 1 And .Cells(1).Value = "" Then lastrowsheet2 = 0
    End With
    ' Get user input for a search term
    Dim userinput As String
    userinput = InputBox("Enter a value to search for.", "Column A Search")
    ' Search for value
    Dim findrange As Range
    Dim firstaddress As String
    Set findrange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Find(what:=userinput, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If findrange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No matching search results"
    Else
        firstaddress = findrange.Address
        Do
            lastrowsheet2 = lastrowsheet2 + 1
            ' Copy values in found row to sheet 2, in new last row
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & lastrowsheet2, "AL" & lastrowsheet2).Value _
                = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & findrange.Row, "AL" & findrange.Row).Value
            ' Find next match
            Set findrange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").FindNext(findrange)
            ' Loop until the Find has wrapped back around, or value not found any more
        Loop While Not findrange Is Nothing And findrange.Address <> firstaddress
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: @ wolfie This works great. The only think is that there are multiple lines for some data. Column A has my qualifier and column AL has the date. Is there anyway I can have the prompt ask me to specify which row to move based on the date, or refer to a cell where I've indicated the year of the data I want to move?

Comment: When inside the `Do` loop you could have another `InputBox` or do get another range. Careful if you do another `Find` then you won't be able to use `FindNext`, but you can just Find again instead. I advise accepting this answer for this question, having a go, and posting another question for this problem. Thanks